# ElementFormDefault="unqualified" ignored using XJC

Tags: java, xml, xjc

I am generating java model classes using XJC from a schema and I don't want  elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED to appear in my package-info.java. I tried two different XMLs-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.google.com/Protocol" elementFormDefault="unqualified" 
targetNamespace="http://www.google.com/Protocol" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
  <xs:element name="A">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="User" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="Attr" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element ref="A1"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
<xs:element name="A1">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Attr" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Attr2" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:element ref="A" />
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Above Xml generates package-info as below-

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.google.com/Protocol")
package com.google;
```

While on other hand below Xml-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.google.com/Protocol" elementFormDefault="unqualified" 
targetNamespace="http://www.google.com/Protocol" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
  <xs:element name="A">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="User" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element ref="A1"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
<xs:element name="A1">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Attr" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:element ref="A" />
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

generates below package-info.java

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.google.com/Protocol", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.google;
```

I don't want elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED to appear in my java file. Currently I have to manually edit it to elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED once the model are generated.

Can anyone please help why elementFormDefault="unqualified" is getting ignored in second xml.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing's necessarily wrong here (apologies if you realize this already).

The JAXB provider is just taking a guess at what you'll do with this package, but this doesn't affect any generated classes, only new ones you might add to that package.

All the generated classes will marshal just fine, local elements will not be written with a NS like you'd expect with **elementFormDefault=unqualified**, since they've been generated with a complete set of JAXB annotations.

Maybe you already know that, and I'm not answering your question, but I'm picturing you thinking this is a bug you need to deal with and just pointing out it won't be if you're going top-down and just using the generated classes.

But for a real answer why there's a difference here, you'd probably have to dive into the implementation details and JAXB provider doc to understand better.  I also don't see a standard binding customization [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html) so that too would probably be provider-specific.

Comment: I checked JAXB and sadly it didn't serve the purpose. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I found one more [link](http://metro.1045641.n5.nabble.com/JAXB-not-respecting-elementFormDefault-for-types-with-only-referred-element-tp1063047p1063048.html) on web. It is a XML issue rather than XJC. I am still looking for a solution though.

Comment: I'm not sure that comment captures the issue.   No idea if JAXB is a good fit for you or not.   But my point was that I don't think there's any issue with the schema-defined elements and types, and there's nothing wrong with the generated classes.  If you try a simple sample program serializing some object instances of the generated JAXB classes, you'll see the NS-qualifier is valid according to the schema.   But JAXB is also allowing for the fact that you could for whatever reason add other classes to this package.